# Adding dependency to build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javafx-8, javafxports

Consider the build.gradle below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.rameses.Main'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

And I want to add a new dependency

```
 dependencies {
     compile files('libs/custom.jar')
 }
```

**QUESTION :** How to merge two dependencies together? I tried something like the code below but it didn't worked, it throws an error. Any Idea?

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b9',
    compile files('libs/custom.jar')
}
```

Comment: question is what you wana achive ? you wana add new plugin's dependency or compile time dependency?

Comment: I developed a small app in JavaFX and I want to deploy it in android, I have a custom jar that I need to add in my project's classpath. Im using Netbeans IDE. Im not sure if it is a plugin depency or compile time depency. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a separate dependencies block to the build gradle like this -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.rameses.Main'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
dependencies {
compile files('libs/custom.jar')
//other dependencies - go here
}
```